Safety of demolition with lead contaminated wood paint/stain
I want renovate my deck (falling apart) and basement (needs insulation and drywall/lighting). I have had a hazmat survey done (required in order to get a bin rental for demo waste). Both areas have wood that has been stained and with are contaminated with lead.

Professionally removing the lead contaminated wood will cost upward of $10k CAD.
I am waiting on the results of a leach ability test for the contaminated samples. Assuming the test is negative, from what I understand of my local regulations the waste would not be considered "hazerdous", and could be disposed of normally at a landfill. The hazmat report does indicate that removing the lead contaminated material is "moderate danger":

However, from what I understand the lead concentration in the deck/basement is relatively low. There are children and possibly a soon to be pregnant woman in the house, so I don't want to mess around with Lead, but I also simply can't afford the professional remediation. Do I need to put off the demo/reno for a bit to save up for the remediation? (The Hazmat report and test results are only valid for ~1 year...), or is this level of lead contamination relatively safe to demo myself given I wear a proper face mask and use ventilation/vacuuming/etc? Most of the lead painted wood is basically falling apart anyway, the majority of the demo would be prying/pulling the wood away, not cutting/sawing/grinding/etc.

Lead is bad if ingested(eaten/drinking).  Your main problem is collecting all of the paint chips that will fall off and you cannot find them after.  Vacuums are good, but they do not pick up paints chips ground into the ground by your shoes.
